# How to stop .Net NuGet Package Manager from installing other packages while installing Npgsql Package

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package, npgsql

I'm adding the PosGreSQL NuGet Package to my solution. As a part of this, there are list of other NuGet Packages that are getting installed automatically which I don't intend to install. How to get rid of this?
Below are the packages installed automatically along with PosGreSQL Nuget Package.
Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.7.0.0, Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode.1.1.1, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.6.0.0, System.Buffers.4.5.1, System.Collections.Immutable.7.0.0, System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.6.0.0, System.Memory.4.5.5, System.Numerics.Vectors.4.5.0, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.6.0.0, System.Text.Encodings.Web.7.0.0, System.Text.Json.7.0.0, System.Threading.Channels.7.0.0, System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.4, System.ValueTuple.4.5.0

I tried deleting the additional Nuget packages manually but Build Solution again adds these NuGet Packages.

Comment: Why don't you want these _dependent_ packages? The PostgreSQL package needs these to function.

Comment: Npgsql only has most of these dependencies when targeting old versions of .NET (are you using .NET Framework)? In modern versions of .NET, only 1-2 dependencies are brought in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to get rid of this?

You don't. Because those are dependencies of the [package you *want* to install](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql). The package you want to use *needs* those other packages to work.

You should basically just not worry about them, unless a dependency causes a very specific issue. You could potentially pick and choose between different versions of the package you want, to try to find a version with fewer dependencies, but that's not *normally* worth doing.

Comment: @Simal If this answers your question, then please accept Jon Skeet's answer.